# Optimizing a continuous function of discrete variables: what type of problem is this?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

Consider a function of $N_a$ discrete variables (on the order of 1000), each of which can take one of $N_b$ different states (on the order of 10). The function result is a single, real number. For example, with $N_a=5$ and $N_b=3$:

$f(1,2,3,1,2)=5.234$

$f(1,2,3,3,3)=-1.68$

I am trying to optimize this function, so I am looking into optimization methods. Unfortunately my background is not in mathematics and I don't know exactly what to search for. I am familiar with non-discrete optimization methods like gradient descent and the Metropolis algorithm, etc. I have looked into graph coloring, barely scratching the surface of combinatorial optimization, but I haven't found an example where my problem fits. I'd be obliged if someone could point me in the right direction by telling me what *type* of problem this is.

Edit:

The underlying problem is kind of a graph-coloring problem; I have a graph of $N_a$ vertices, each one can take a "color" from one of $N_b$ values. The function result is a kind of "interaction energy" depending on the color of each neighbor of each vertex. It's kind of like an Ising model on a semi-random graph. There are some rules on the distribution of "colors", like each color must be represented by at least one vertex. I started out by using Metropolis sampling/simulated annealing, but I wasn't sure if there is a more efficient route to optimization already traced for me, based on purer mathematics. Because the set of "colors" and vertices are discrete, it's a little out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: Are there any more assumptions about the function? Without those, in the worst case it's a brute-force-$N_b^{N_a}$-different-inputs problem.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I just updated to give a little more background. I also gave brute-force a try (coupled with a little Monte Carlo), but the results haven't been great so far (as one would expect!).